# Do you go blind and deaf when you see through the eyes of a sentinel raven, like a regular familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, familiars, unearthed-arcana

I have a warlock player who chose Patron of the Raven Queen giving him Sentinel Raven. I'm familiar with the *Find Familiar* spell which says:

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any Special senses that the familiar has. **During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses**.

Is this still the case with the [Sentinel Raven from the Raven Queen Patron?](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/20170213_Wizrd_Wrlck_UAv2_i48nf.pdf)

I know the sentinel raven is not a familiar, but the mechanic seems too similar and I'm afraid I might have missed something. I just doesn't seem right that you can see through two sets of eyes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Nope. The Raven spirit is superior to familiars in this regard.

> You can see through the raven’s eyes and hear what it hears while it is within 100 feet of you.

Now I will caution you that Unearthed Arcana is playtest material, and is not yet refined. The Raven will likely see specific wording to fix this. Currently, it does not have it, and in D&D, features do what they say they do. Right now, this does NOT blind you and make you deaf. You simply get to experience two sets of input simultaneously.